# PHP syntax only store last value of the array

Tags: php, mysql

need help with this syntax it only stores the last value of my array into the database.

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $lines=preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $_POST['text']);


        foreach($lines as $line => $value)
        $quer = "INSERT INTO wew (wewe) VALUES('$value')";
        if ($conn->query($quer) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $quer . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add bracket to your foreach. Without that, only the next line will be in the loop.

so you should have:

```
foreach($lines as $line => $value) {
    $quer = "INSERT INTO wew (wewe) VALUES('$value')";
    if ($conn->query($quer) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    }
}
```

I advice you to use bracket for all your conditions and loops since the readability is better and you avoid errors like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($lines as $line => $value) { // Add braces near foreach
    $quer = "INSERT INTO wew (wewe) VALUES('$value')";
    if ($conn->query($quer) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $quer . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}// close foreach
```